# How to make modal with JQuery and Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to make a modal with css and jquery. this is my html:

```
<a class="logreg">Login</a>
<div class="login-modal">some text here</div>
```

and my jquery:

```
var login_modal = false;

$(".logreg").click(function(){

    if (login_modal === false) {
        $(".login-modal").fadeIn();
        login_modal = true;
    } else {
        $(".login-modal").fadeOut();
        login_modal = false;
    }

});
```

everything work well. but first i don't want to use fade in and fade out. I want the modal just come on screen with getting bigger.

second, I want to the whole page excluding my modal div get dark. not opacity. i want a black layer on it that make it dark. how can I do these?

Comment: Please don't expect us to write code for you. We will only guide you.

Comment: For zooming in/out, you can toggle a css class and then add desired styles to it. For darker background, you need another wrapper div that will act as background of this modal div.

Comment: I tried another div it did't work!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, but there is way more work to make it usable :)

//edit: no animation added, but there is a lot of tutorials for that :)

```js
$(".logreg").click(function(){
  $('.login-modal').addClass('visible');
  $('.black-layer').fadeIn();
});
$(".close-modal").click(function(){
  $('.login-modal').removeClass('visible');
  $('.black-layer').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.login-modal {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.black-layer {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  z-index: 10;
}

.login-modal.visible {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  z-index: 50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="logreg">Login</a>
<div class="black-layer"></div>
<div class="login-modal">
<span class="close-modal">X</span>
some text here
</div>
```